# Prolog list length comparison return true/false

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a function longer(S1,S2) which should be true if S1 is longer than S2, otherwise false. What I have so far is the following:

```
longer(A,nil). 
longer(nil,B) :- false.
longer([A,AS],[B,BS]) :- longer(AS,BS).
```

But for some reason I cannot seem to get it to parse correctly when I provide for instance the input: `longer([1,2],[1]).`
But when I run the above through swi-prolog it return false.

Another example is running the: `longer([1],nil)` which also return false, even though it should be true by matching with list(cons(A,As)) where As = nil, finally matching the end clause.

What am I missing? Can someone point me in the right direction here, as I cannot see how this is not evaluating to true.

**Edit:** it should be noted that I am still fairly new to prolog at this point.

**Update** I have had some misunderstanding in relation to what is common prolog semantic. Including trying to force the program to yield a false value (probably being steered by my understanding of non-declarative language semantics). I have updated my answer with the inputs from @tiffi.

Comment: what is nil and cons?

Comment: @tiffi `nil` is the equivalent to the empty list `[]` in prolog. cons is a prolog operator than represents a binary functor, such that: `cons(1,cons(2,cons(3,nil)))` is equavalent to `1.2.3.nil` or `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: ?- nil=[].
false.

?- cons(1,cons(2,cons(3,nil)))=[1,2,3].
false.

Comment: It is what I have been taught briefly, and also read it several places - so this assumption is based on what is being told to me.

Comment: Do you have any source on that? Are you sure that referred to swi-prolog?

Comment: @tiffi the documentation I have found online is eg: http://www.irisa.fr/prive/ridoux/ICLP91/node7.html among others. But none of these are well documented! So I may just assume their correctness due to lack of experience. This is also my first introduction to declarative programming.

Comment: As far as I can see, with "nil" and "cons" he refers to some theoretical definition of lists, not prolog notation - note also that he doesn't use either of them in his prolog examples :-)

Comment: @tiffi That's Olivier Ridoux himself writing in 1998, and this is about Lambda-Prolog, which is "another Prolog". For documentation links about "the" Prolog (i.e. anything near to ISO Prolog), check: [this list](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=manual) (for example). For list, this: [Lists](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a solution that is pretty close to the thinking behind what you have come up with:

```
longer([_|_],[]).
longer([_|As], [_|Bs]):- longer(As,Bs).
```

Your idea with regard to the first clause (before your edit) could be expressed like this:

```
longer(A,[]):- is_list(A). %is_list/1 is inbuilt
```

However, that doesn't give you the right result, since the empty list is also a list. Thus you need to make sure that the first argument is a non-empty list.